# The meaning of "zip tip"

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is the meaning of "zip tip" in "[strong Zip Tip does not sheer off when self-drilling](https://www.amazon.ca/CONFAST-Self-Drilling-Drywall-Hollow-Wall-Anchors/dp/B07WS1GF52?th=1)"? Is it some type of [zip fastener](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/zip) that is part of an anchor, so to speak? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a name invented by the Confast company, the maker of the product, not 'dictionary English'. The capital Z and T are clues that the phrase is a commercial term.

The 'Zip Tip' is the special tip that does not 'sheer off' (break off) when drilling. Note in British English we would spell it 'shear'.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty certain we'd spell it "shear" in American English, too, and this might just be a typo.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your explanations!

Comment: I have a feeling that while the company cannot patent the idea of a zig-zag shaped tip (because it is common and has been done before), they can probably claim copyright over the name 'Zip Tip' (with capital letters - typography is important) and therefore prevent rival companies using the term.